# Зазывала, человек «на входе», - что именно кавычить (см.)?

Tags: кавычки

> При подходе к траттории в Риме нередко работает профессионал —
>   зазывала. Очень занятная профессия. И ведь жизнь ресторана в
>   туристическом квартале зачастую зависит именно от него. **Хорошо у
>   тебя человек «на входе стоит»** — у тебя бизнес идёт. Нет — хоть
>   плачь! На каждый шаг — несколько заведений, в жесткой конкуренции.

*На каждый шаг - на каждом шагу* сознательно не трогаю, тире за меня работает, но вот кавычки...

Может, страшно помыслить... закавычить только «стоит»?

(Он же не стоит, а выкаблучивается.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хорошо у тебя человек ***на входе стоит*** — у тебя бизнес идёт. Нет — хоть плачь!

Можно не ставить кавычки. В предыдущем тексте сказано, что это зазывала, вот и понятно, о чем речь.

Если очень надо выделить, то можно **курсив** использовать